# Why is reading a bitmap so slow in Racket?

Tags: racket

I'm writing a CRUD app to learn Racket. Each item has an image associated with it, so I'm using `read-bitmap` to open the file and load the bitmap. Only one bitmap is loaded at a time, initiated by user-selection in a `list-box%`. Without drawing to any context, this operation takes ~5 seconds to load a 2-3MB jpeg. Why is it so slow? Is there a better way?

I figured I was doing something wrong in the application so I tried `read-bitmap` in DrRacket, which led to the same slowness:

```lisp
#lang racket/gui
(require racket/draw)

(read-bitmap "/path/to/my.JPEG")
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the image you're using so I can try this out for myself?

Comment: I can confirm that this is catastrophically slow, as is `pict`'s `bitmap` procedure.  JPEGs seem to be heroically slow, PNGs are merely painful (Racket 7.9, OSX, Intel) I'd report this as a bug.

Comment: I suspect that part of the problem is that jpegs seem to be not just decompressed, but also copied byte by byte after decompressing, in Racket code. The Racket mailing list is usually a friendly place for questions, and there are many more Racket experts there than here.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll follow up there

Answer (score 0):

FYI this was fixed in a later build. The question was using Racket v7.9, but 8.x builds fixed this.

https://github.com/racket/racket/issues/3669